# If the condition `property in object` is true, why does TypeScript not infer the type of object[property] to be the union type of object's values?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, index-signature

I'm trying to access `object[property]`, and TypeScript is throwing the `element implicitly has any type` error.

```
const getValue = (key: string) => {
  const object = {
    property0: 14
    property1: -3
  }

  if (!(key in object)) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid key: ${key}`)
  }

  return object[key]
}
```

If we don't know whether `property in object` is true, we'd have to provide TypeScript with the index signature ourselves. That is, TypeScript *should* throw an error if we removed the `if(!(key in object))` condition from that function, until we manually note the index signature of `object`.

But it seems like, given we know at compile-time that `key` is in `object` when we make it to the return statement, TypeScript should throw no such error for this function, and should instead infer the return type of `getValue` to be `number`.

I can resolve the issue by manually noting the index signature of `object`:

```
interface ObjectWithOnlyNumberProperties {
  [key: string]: number
}

const getValue = (key: string) => {
  const object: ObjectWithOnlyNumberProperties = {
    property0: 14
    property1: -3
  }

  if (!(key in object)) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid key: ${key}`)
  }

  return object[key]
}
```

But it seems like I shouldn't have to, and the type of `object[key]` should be inferable at compile-time to `typeof property0 | typeof property1` since we know that `key in object` is true.

Comment: Because at compile time Typescript is dealing with type not actual object : 
and by default `{ property0: 14, property1: -3 }` is typed as `{ property0: number, property1: number }`.

A type in Typescript is a minimal contract accordance, so as far as typescript knows `{ property0: number, property1: number }` type could refer to Actual Object like `{ property0: 14, property1: -3, property2: "string" }`.

Obviously We knows that in your code it won`t, but TS don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying Romain Laurent's comment, which answers the question perfectly!

> At compile time, TypeScript is dealing with types, not actual objects.
> By default, `{ property0: 14, property1: -3 }` is typed as `{ property0: number, property1: number }`. A type in TypeScript is a
> minimal contract accordance, so as far as TypeScript knows, the `{ property0: number, property1: number }` type could refer to an actual
> object like `{ property0: 14, property1: -3, property2: "string" }`.
> Obviously, we know in the code that it won't, but TypeScript doesn't
> know that. And as the above case indicates, `object[property]` is of
> type `any`, since `property2` could be of *any* type, not just `string`.

Update: as per geoffrey's comment, if you're using target library `es2022` or later, you should also update the above code to use `Object.hasOwn(object, property)` instead of `property in object`, to protect against prototype pollution.

Comment: This is unrelated to your TS issue and the workaround you found, but know that it is not true that "we know that it won't" https://tsplay.dev/Nd26XW

Comment: Hmm—how do you mean? On that TSPlay, I see the error `Property '__proto__' does not exist on type '{}'.` rather than the output `KABOOM!` Afaik, the __proto__ initializer only applies to the object for which it was set (`unrelated`), not for generic objects? So even if I change the first couple lines to `const unrelated = { __proto__: { boom: 'KABOOM!' } }` and the code compiles, it'll just exit with the expected `Invalid key: boom`. If there were a way in JS to set the default prototype for all objects, we indeed wouldn't "know that it won't", but I don't believe JS has that functionality?

Comment: if you run the code, you will see `"KABOOM"` in the console. That's the problem. It's called prototype pollution and it is as bad as you probably now realise it is. One way to guard from it is to use `Object.hasOwn(object, key)` in place of `key in object` because you will be sure to check for own properties and exclude properties inherited from the prototype. You can also create naked objects like so `Object.assign(Object.create(null), {foo: 1, bar: 2})`: such objects do not have prototypes, contrary to object literals, and are immune to prototype pollution.

Comment: Note that currently `Object.hasOwn` has no useful type declaration: it returns `boolean` so there will be no type narrowing, but it should come "soon". In the meantime you can patch it https://tsplay.dev/wQYMJw

Comment: Makes sense! Obviously `Object.hasOwn` won't work for older target libraries, but updating the answer to reflect that this is the right approach for `es2022` or later. Thanks!

Comment: `Object.hasOwn` has pollyfills https://tsplay.dev/w6Lyrm. I did not try to transpile to it yet. I saw a babel plugin but it relies on `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` which could itself be redefined so I don't recommend it.